# Is there a way to run multiple of a script on a html site

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wanna use it on multiple HTML elements but have not had any luck, like have a 2nd element that countsdown to a different time

Because I tried to change all the variable names in the 2nd script (copy of the script with HTML element id changed, variable and function names changed) and it was giving no output.

This is it

```
(function() {
  var start = new Date;
  start.setHours(15, 10, 0); // 11pm

  function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
  }

  function tick() {
    var now = new Date;
    if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
    var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
    var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
    var ss = pad(remain % 60);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =
      hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a function, find the elements then pass the elements to the countdown timer which then mutates the elements innerHTML etc.

If you want different times then use [`data` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to set params on the element which you can get from `elm.dataset.somename`, see docs

```js
function countdown(elm) {
  var start = new Date;
  start.setHours(elm.dataset.h || 0, elm.dataset.m || 0, elm.dataset.s || 0); // from dataset

  function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
  }

  function tick() {
    var now = new Date;
    if (now > start) { // too late, go to tomorrow
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
    var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
    var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
    var ss = pad(remain % 60);
    elm.innerHTML =
      hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }
  tick();
}

document.querySelectorAll('.timer').forEach(countdown)
```

```html
<div class="timer" data-h="1" data-m="10" data-s="0"></div>
<div class="timer" data-h="3" data-m="15" data-s="5"></div>
<div class="timer" data-h="6" data-m="20" data-s="10"></div>
<div class="timer" data-h="12" data-m="30" data-s="59"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to finish my school work, if you want to check it out

https://whstime.github.io/whs/